# How to get Json Array Content to ArrayList<String> in Java?

Tags: android, arrays, json, arraylist

I have Json file in android "Assets" folder. Json file have more then five arrays how to store into Java ArrayList or how to directly get Json Array to forLoop.

Comment: did you try something?. put that here.

Comment: like Random Question Generated from Json Array in TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this way**

```
 public static String AssetJSONFile (String filename, Context context) throws IOException {
    AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream file = manager.open(filename);
    byte[] formArray = new byte[file.available()];
    file.read(formArray);
    file.close();

    return new String(formArray);
  }         

   public void getJson()
   { 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Context context = null;
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap;

    try {
        String jsonLocation = AssetJSONFile("yourjson.json", context);
        String id;
        String question;

        JSONArray JsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arjuna");
        {
              for (int k = 0; k < JsonArray.length(); k++) 
             {  
              JSONObject jsonObject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(k);

              id= JSONObject.getString("id");
              question= JSONObject.getString("question");

              hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
              hashMap.put("id", id);
              hashMap.put("question", question);

              formList.add(hashMap); 
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("json.txt");
            String s = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("arjuna");
            HashMap hashMap = null;
            ArrayList<HashMap> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                int id = obj.getInt("id");
                String question = obj.getString("question");
                hashMap = new HashMap();
                hashMap.put("id", id);
                hashMap.put("question", question);
                arrayList.add(hashMap);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```